# Surface RT in IE10 drag and drop (touchscreen only)

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, touch, internet-explorer-10

I'm having an issue with developing a drag and drop Div in ASP.NET for the Surface RT(using the touchscreen). Currently, dragging and dropping these items on other tablets (unable to test other browsers, Surface RT only has IE), work just fine, but the controls for the IE10 seem to override the drag event with the scroll or right click event. I was wondering if anyone has found a work around or came cross this issue just for the Windows RT IE 10 problem. (there is no issue with other OSs for tablets or their browsers)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your elements you wish to drag/drop, just add this css directive to their class:

```
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

That way, you prevent windows RT from applying their default touch event handlers to those elements